# не удается преобразовать из uint в int

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Дан массив размера N и целые числа K и L (1 ≤ K ≤ L ≤ N). Найти суммуе элементов массива с номерами от K до L включительно.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Lab8task16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введиите N");
            uint N;
            bool q = uint.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out N);
            if (q)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Введите K");
                uint K;
                bool f = uint.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out K);
                if (f)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите L");
                    uint L;
                    bool g = uint.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out L);
                    if (g == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Неверное значение L");
                    }
                    if (g)
                    {
                        uint sum = 0;
                        uint[] a = Enumerable.Repeat(3, N).ToArray();
                        for (uint i = K+1; i < L; i++)
                        {
                            sum = a[K] + a[i];
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(sum);

                    }
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Неверное значение K");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Неверное значение N");
        }
        
    }
}
```

В выводе пишет ошибку преобразования из uint в int в данной строке
`uint[] a = Enumerable.Repeat(3, N).ToArray();`

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так, не могу разобраться

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat((uint)3, N).ToArray()` потому что для целочисленных литералов по умолчанию используется `int`. Вообще для удобства в таких простых приложениях лучше используйте `int` до тех пор, пока вам явно `uint` не понадобится.

Comment: @aepot спасибо!

Comment: Проверить что число положительное можно например так `if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int n) && n > 0)`